# How to prevent "Call requires API level" from 3rd party libraries

Tags: android, android-proguard, android-studio-3.0

### App Code

When we use some code in our Android application that does not exist in the min-version SDK, Android Studio will show an error about it.

**Example**:
Let's assume my app has target SDK 26 and min SDK 21 and my code tries to call `Objects.isNull(var);`: then we get a nice error-message:

```
Call requires API level 24 (current min is 21): java.util.Objects#isNull
```

AFAIK this is a [Lint](http://tools.android.com/recent/lintapicheck) message (not a compiler warning or error).

### Third party code

How can we have the same checks for 3rd party java libraries?

**Example**:
when the project depends on a `lib.jar` file and this library internally uses `Objects.isNull`, then we don't get any error/warning and the app will crash on older devices.

One way to avoid this is to make **[Instrumentation Tests](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/index.html#create_instrumented_test_for_a_build_variant)** - but these tests are slow and you never have 100% code coverage.

e.g. I actually thought that **ProGuard** should report this issue. But it doesn't.
Maybe because it uses the *target* Android SDK *min* SDK?

So what can we do about this in the following 2 situations:

1. we must use the 3rd party library as it is
2. we can fork the 3rd party library and can use this fork: what could we do to find/avoid these errors: e.g. should we convert it to an aar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can we have the same checks for 3rd party java libraries?

Add the source code to your project.

> we must use the 3rd party library as it is

Ask its developers what the relevant `minSdkVersion` is for the library, then set yours to match, or otherwise avoid calling their library on older devices.

> we can fork the 3rd party library and can use this fork: what could we do to find/avoid these errors: e.g. should we convert it to an aar?

Add the source code to your project. Or, create some other project with the source code. Lint checks source code, not compiled code. If you create some other project with the source code, you would need to have it compile a JAR or AAR and make that available to your main project.

Comment: Too bad, that these checks are not done on the final byte-code after ProGuard has removed all unused code..